# Make ModelItem clickable inside a View and send you to next page with item.Id (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For the moment User can comment a review and all comments related to its review is displaying under the review(like youtube). You can also see the `UserName` that created the comment.

What I want to do now is to make visible `UserName` clickable and send you to another page(with it's users `Id`) where you can see details about that user. I'm new to MVC and I've no clue how to do so.

The code below is my poorly attempt to do so, but gives you an idea what I had in mind:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.UserName)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @Html.ActionLink(item.User.UserName, "VisitUser", new { item.User.Id }))
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

**The code below is my controller code for displaying the user:**

```
  public ActionResult VisitUser(Guid id) {

        if (id == null) {
            return Content("Something went wrong..");
        }
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null) {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

View for `VisitUSer` looks like the View above, but without the `@Html.ActionLink..` attempt.

RouteConfig:

```
 public class RouteConfig {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.User.UserName, 
                "VisitUser", "User", new { id = item.User.Id }, null))
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it wont work with "`null`" inside that. With null `VisitUser` and `User`'s `Action`/`Controller` cant be resolved. However, if I remove `null`, it seems to work. But then I get a null-error: `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method`. I guess it's something wrong with my controller code?

Comment: Sorry - think I got the nulls the wrong way round https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: The edited code still doesn't work for `null`, as `VisitUser` and `User` can't still be resolved.

Comment: Try checking how the html is rendered. Is it possible that an null id is being passed in the model? it should look something like this `<a href='/User/VisitUser/84986578-a929-4d44-ba0f-794840e0303b'>UserNameFromModel<\a>`

Comment: This is how my URL looks like when I get null-error: `http://localhost:41003/Review/VisitUser?Length=4`. I tried to check if `User.Id` were null by simply replacing `...Item.User.UserName ...` with `... item.User.Id.ToString()...` in your code and the Guid value were not null. So I guess I'm not sending a null value from the view?

Comment: Hmmm - something to do with your route config?

Comment: Don't think so, added route config in my post above, as it would be harder to read in comment.

Comment: Aah it's working now. I accidentally messed somewhere else that caused this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @Html.ActionLink(item.User.UserName, "VisitUser", new { item.User.Id }))
```

To

```
@Html.ActionLink("Visit User", "VisitUser", "User", new {id = item.User.Id }, null)
```

You should be good to show

Comment: It won't work with null as `VisitUser` and `User`'s Action/Controller would not be resolved then. Works if I remove `null`, but then I get a null error: `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method`.